# How to make more than 1 page in the same form?

Tags: c#

How to make more than 1 page in the same form like the screenshots below?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Use tabs. A little bit of research and investigation into .NET controls would easily show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Which framework are you using?  For Windows Forms, the easiest way would be to use a control called a TabControl.  Each "page" is considered a tab.

Comment: It's not really possible to answer the question in a valid way without the OP providing more information.